# Uploading multiple photos in a form

Tags: php, html, file-upload, photo

I have a photo-upload form that allows a user to upload 1 photo.  But my users are complaining that they want to upload many photos.  How can I allow them to do that?

Right now I have this form for uploading:
http://www.hikingsanfrancisco.com/account/upload_hike_photos.php?hike_id=58

(I tried to paste code, but it didn't work somehow)

Any thoughts how to best go about it?  Is there a way to loop through the selected files maybe?  (I am using PHP)

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add more fields for uploading files, I don't know, maybe file or six, and the upload button will check through php which of them have information to start the upload, 1 at a time or course, in a php loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plugin that uses flash + javascript (MooTools) to do file upload.  The upside to this plugin is that it's supported and you can [Github](https://github.com/digitarald/digitarald-fancyupload) it. It can have **multiple photo uploads,** limit max size, etc, and verify file information **before** upload.  Also, has example for backend using PHP on how files are handled after it is uploaded.

[Fancyupload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/)

Features

- Select and upload multiple files
- Filter files by type in the select
- dialog A lot of possible Events to
  add your own behaviour
- Show and filter useful file information before
  the upload starts
- Limit uploads by file count, type or size
- Platform and server independent, just needs Flash9+ (> 95% penetration) which works on all browsers with it installed

Here is the jQuery plugin that does the same as the MooTools one:

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/)

Answer (score 1):

Add new file inputs. Or use smth like [swfuploader](http://www.swfupload.org/) for file uploading.